# How can I remove/hide entries from the Command Palette in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have just installed a [bookmarks plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Sublime%20Bookmarks) that works better than the native bookmarks implementation.
When I open the command palette (`Shift+Cmd+P`) and type `Bookmarks`, commands of both tools are shown.
I only want to see the commands related to the plugin.
How can I hide the native bookmarks commands from the command palette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the `Default.sublime-commands` file. You can use https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer to navigate to `Default/Default.sublime-commands`. Remove the appropriate entries  and save. The plugin will place the override file in the proper location. Note that this completely overrides the default file. That is, if some update is made to that file, you will not see the updates automatically.